# Is it a design pattern? Then which one? Can I use this other than entity related operation?

Tags: java, design-patterns, entity

I see this type of practice when working hibernate dao with spring. Is the below implementation a design pattern?

```
public interface BroadCastI<T, ID>  {
}

public abstract class BroadCastImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements BroadCastI<T, ID> {
}

public interface HttpBroadCastI extends BroadCastI<HttpBroadCast, String>  {
}

public class HttpBroadCastImpl extends BroadCastImpl<HttpBroadCast, String> implements HttpBroadCastI {
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what?

Comment: i see this type of practice when working hibernate dao with spring is this the above implementation a design pattern?

Comment: Every design pattern I have ever seen involves methods at some stage.  This does not.  So as it's currently written, the answer is no.

Comment: so what do i consider it as i have seen this a lot of time when working on crud operation where ORM is involved